# Chrome extension Invalid value for 'icons' error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to load my manifest.json file into chrome extension while in developer mode. However, when I click "Load Unpacked" I receive and error message which says "Invalid value for 'icons'." which means that Chrome cannot load the manifest.

The icons are within a file called "icons" which is in the same folder as the manifold.json file. Really struggling to understand the error. Here is my code:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Assessment tool",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Scrapes information from website and performs a set of calculations",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "/icons/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.16.png",
        "sizes": "16x16",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "/icons/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "/icons/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.128.png",
        "sizes": "128x128",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_icon": "/icons/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.16.png",
      "default_title": "Assessment tool",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://www.assessment.co.uk/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [
          "/popup.css",
          "/popup.html",
          "/script.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
          "https://*/*",
          "http://*/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be here?

I tried taking the files out of the folder called icons and just referencing them directly in the code but this also did not work...

Comment: Format your manifest.json properly. It's impossible to read otherwise.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, thank you for flagging. Hopefully you can read the code now?

Comment: You've invented a non-existent syntax of `icons`. Use the [documented syntax](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/icons/).

Comment: @gator123 - Did you ask ChatGPT to generate your manifest.json? Because that would explain the non-existent "icons" syntax. ChatGPT loves making stuff up out of thin air. If you didn't use ChatGPT, I'd love to know where you found the "icons" syntax you used, or if you invented it yourself.